# Regex number and hyphen

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match number with regular expression like:

```
34-7878-3523-4233
```

with this:

```
^[0-9][0-9-]*-[0-9-]*[0-9]$
```

But the expression also allow

34--34--------88

So how can I allow only one hyphen between the number?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Your regex:

See it in action: **[Regexr.com](http://regexr.com?3382c)**

```
^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$
```

### Matches:

```
1-2
1-2-3
```

### Doesn't match:

```
1
1-
1-2-
1-2----3
1---3
```

Comment: Thanks but for me there should exist at least one hyphen

Answer (score 8):

That's because, you have included the hyphen in the allowed characters in your character class. You should have it outside.

You can try something like this: -

```
^([0-9]+-)*[0-9]+$
```

Now this will match 0 or more repetition of *some digits followed by a hyphen*. Then one or more digits at the end.

Comment: It just allow with one hyphen with single digit like `3-3-3`. I want to match like `232424-42-2455`

Comment: @vusan. No it will match multiple digit now. I forgot to put quantifiers.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `normal*(special normal*)*` pattern:

```
^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$
```

where `normal` is `[0-9]` and `special` is `-`