# How to write a regex for digits separated by - in python

Tags: python, regex

I have to write a regex for digits separated by -.
eg. 12-13-25-69

I tried (-?)[\d{2}]\1 but all the test cases are not passing.
It is failing when -12-36-98-86 or 12-36-98-78-36 test cases are coming.

Comment: Is `-12-36-98-86` valid?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi no it's not a valid input.The proper input is xx-xx-xx-xx where x is a digit.

Comment: You answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030886/3832970).

Comment: Does this help? `^(\d{2})*(?:-\d{2})*$`

Comment: What is your expected output? All two digits in the text? If yes, you can use only `(\d+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my output should consist of only 8 digits where - is optional.
but the solution provided by you is accepting more than 8 digits.

Comment: @RaviRanjan `^-?([0-9]{2}-){3}[0-9]{2}$`? Please update the question with the real requirements, else it does seem a dupe.